# Full Text Search with multiple index and complex requirements

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, solr, search-engine, sphinx

We are building an application which will require us to index data for each of our users so that we can provide full text search on their data. Here are some notable things about the application:

A) The data for every user is totally unrelated to every other user. This gives us few advantages:

1. we can keep our indexes small in
   size.
2. merging/compatcting fragmented index
   will take less time.
3. if some indexes becomes inaccessible
   for whatever reason (corruption?),
   only those users gets affected.
   Other users are unaffected and the
   service is available for them.

B) Each user can have few different types of data. We want to keep each type in separate folders, for the same reasons as above.

So, our index hierarchy will look something like:

`/user1/type1/<index files>

 /user1/type2/<index files>

 /user2/type1/<index files>

 /user3/type3/<index files>`

C) Often, probably with every itereation, we'll add "types" of data that can be indexed.
So we want to have an efficient/programmatic way to add schemas for different "types". We would like to avoid having fixed schema for indexing. I like Lucene's schema-less way of indexing stuff.

D) The users can fire search queries which will search either:
 - Within a specific "type" for that user
 - Across all types for that user: in this case we want to fire a parallel query like Lucene has. ([ParallelMultiSearcher](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/ParallelMultiSearcher.html))

E) We require real time update for the index. *This is a must.*

F) We are are planning to shard our index across multiple machines. For this also, we want:
 if a shard becomes inaccessible, only those users whose data are residing in that shard gets affected. Other users get uninterrupted service.

We were considering Lucene, Sphinx and Solr to do this. This is what we found:

- Sphinx: No efficient way to do A, B,
  C, F. Or is there?
- Luecne: Everything looks possible, as
  it is very low level. But we have to
  write wrappers to do F and build a
  communication layer between the web
  server and the search server.
- Solr: Not sure if we can do A, B, C
  easily. Can we?

So, my question is what is the best software for the above requirements? I am inclined more towards Solr and then Lucene if we get all the requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see Solr being able to handle A or B, as Solr's model is to have everything in one index (per <strike>shard</strike> core). Solr can handle C if you use the [dynamic field types](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Dynamic_fields). Although Solr can do real time indexing, it is not as fast as Lucene (even with Embedded Solr, in my experience). This all points to Lucene being your only choice.

Comment: bajafresh4life suggestion of using lots of cores is one didn't think of (for some reason I thought of core == shard on another server).

Comment: Does that change your stand on this now ?

Comment: Going strictly on your question specs (A to F) I think Lucene is the best choice as it gives you the most flexibility. However, I'm not convinced you actually need separate index files for each user or need to worry about (A) as it seems like premature optimisation. Solr gives you a lot of free stuff over Lucene (Solr requires a lot less lines of code) but forces you to do things the Solr way. I've rewritten an app that used pure Lucene to using Solr and although it did take a while to understand and appreciate the Solr way of doing things, the end result is a much better user experience.

Answer (score 1):

I think Solr might work really well for you here.

The key feature that Solr has that will work well for you in your sitiuation is the notion of cores.  See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin

One way you can implement this is that each user/type combination can be a separate Solr core.  This satisfies (A) and (B).  The client can either direct the search at a single core, or it can direct the search at multiple cores at once (and optional across different Solr servers), which is what you want when you search across a single user and all types.  This satisfies (D) and (F).  Or you can one core for each user, with a "type" field that you can filter on.

As for (C), Solr has the notion of dynamic fields.  See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Dynamic_fields

As far as (E) goes, Solr doesn't have "true" real-time indexing yet.  But if a lag of a few seconds is acceptable, then Solr can handle that.

Comment: do you think Solr wouldn't complain if there are fairly huge number of users ? What is the ideal number of cores can it have without impact on performance ?  And can it support the folder structure mentioned in _B_ ?

Comment: Solr is designed for high volume, so I wouldn't worry about large numbers of users. You can always scale out to multiple nodes. As for the # of cores question, I don't think having a large number should be an issue, although it's worth testing. I know there is some minimum memory overhead for keeping indexes open, and you may need to up the ulimit for open file handles. Re: folder structure, it probably won't allow for EXACTLY that structure, but you may be able to get close to it.  At least there will be one directory per core.

Comment: See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LotsOfCores .  Looks like the main issue is being able to open and close lots of cores efficiently.

Comment: After reading that, I am really scared to use Solr now... BTW, we are going to use Amazon EC2 instances for this project... We would be having many instances and would prefer spreading index over instances...

Comment: Solr supports multiple cores over multiple nodes, so it would work fine over multiple instances in EC2